# NX-workspace + react + webpack-federation

Tags: reactjs, webpack, monorepo, nrwl-nx, webpack-module-federation

This might be a dummy question, but i've tried in different ways and i can't figure it out.

I created one NX workspace with the following command:

`npx create-nx-workspace@16.9.1 my-workspace --preset=react-monorepo`

then i created two remote applications with the following commands:

`nx g @nx/react:remote inventory --directory=apps/inventory`

`nx g @nx/react:remote shop --directory=apps/shop`

Then i only modified the file **module-federation.config.ts**

to add the following configuration: library info.

Example:

[image: module-federation.config.ts]

Then i executed both remotes with the following command:
    `nx serve inventory`     `nx serve shop`

And so far all is working as intended.

My host application is not in the Nx-workspace, and if i try to load one of the remotes, it continues to work as expected.
When i try to load, both remote in my host application, i receive the following error:

[image]

When i debug the code, i detect that the problem is that federation is trying to compare the oldScope with the sharedScope, and they are different.

**container-entry.js of inventory package**
[image: container-entry.js of inventory package]

**info on both variables**
[image: info in both variables]

What i can't figure it out is why the oldScope of inventory package as a reference to the shop package.

In this host is loaded several remote apps (that aren't in the nx-workspace) and they all work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across with the similar problem, the "fix" i found was to upgrade the versions of the package @nx/react to the latest version (17.2.8), and his subsequent dependencies.

With this upgrade, the problem indicated in this issue doesn't occur anymore.

Thanks